# Difference between python sniffer and unittest discover

Tags: python, python-unittest

What is the difference between running

```
sniffer -x src/tests
```

and

```
python -m unittest discover -s src
```

Is there a preffered way of running tests, and what are pros and cons of each method?

Answer (score 0):

`sniffer` is a third party package for a third party testing framework `nose`.  While `discover` is part of the native python `unittest`  testing framework.   Also `sniffer` looks for changes to tests and runs them when detected. I don't think `discover` does this.